# http API Calling handle status code common function

Tags: android, function, kotlin, http, http-status-codes

Just cast it to

override fun httpErrorHandle(e: Throwable) {
val error = e as ANError
errorMessage(activity!!, error)
}

Answer (score 0):

```
 val error = e as ANError
 showErrorMessage(activity, error.errorCode)
```

```
HTTP status code below function check 
Pass argument - Context and HTTP status code

fun showErrorMessage(activity: Activity, Code: Int) {
    when (Code) {
        0 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_500))
        100 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_100))
        101 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_101))
        103 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_103))
        200 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_200))
        201 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_201))
        202 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_202))
        203 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_203))
        204 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_204))
        205 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_205))
        206 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_206))
        300 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_300))
        301 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_301))
        302 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_302))
        303 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_303))
        304 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_304))
        307 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_307))
        308 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_308))
        400 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_400))
        401 -> {
            unAuthorizedPopUpView(activity)
        }
        402 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_402))
        403 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_403))
        404 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_404))
        405 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_405))
        406 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_406))
        407 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_407))
        408 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_408))
        409 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_409))
        410 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_410))
        411 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_411))
        412 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_412))
        413 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_413))
        414 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_414))
        415 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_415))
        416 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_416))
        417 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_417))
        418 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_418))
        422 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_422))
        425 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_425))
        426 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_426))
        428 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_428))
        429 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_429))
        431 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_431))
        451 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_451))
        500 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_500))
        // 501 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_501))
        501 -> {
            invalidJWTTokenAuth(activity)
        }
        502 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_502))
        503 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_503))
        504 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_504))
        505 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_505))
        506 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_506))
        507 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_507))
        508 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_508))
        511 -> showCustomToastCode(activity, activity.getString(R.string.code_511))
    }
}
```

```
HTTP String message 

 <string name="code_100">Continue</string>
    <string name="code_101">Switching Protocols</string>
    <string name="code_103">Early Hints</string>
    <string name="code_200">OK</string>
    <string name="code_201">Created</string>
    <string name="code_202">Accepted</string>
    <string name="code_203">Non-Authoritative Information</string>
    <string name="code_204">Data Not Available.!</string>
    <string name="code_205">Reset Content</string>
    <string name="code_206">Partial Content</string>
    <string name="code_300">Multiple Choices</string>
    <string name="code_301">Moved Permanently</string>
    <string name="code_302">Found</string>
    <string name="code_303">See Other</string>
    <string name="code_304">Not Modified</string>
    <string name="code_307">Temporary Redirect</string>
    <string name="code_308">Permanent Redirect</string>
    <string name="code_400">Bad Request</string>
    <string name="code_402">Payment Required</string>
    <string name="code_403">Forbidden</string>
    <string name="code_404">Data Not Available.!</string>
    <string name="code_405">Method Not Allowed</string>
    <string name="code_406">Not Acceptable</string>
    <string name="code_407">Proxy Authentication Required</string>
    <string name="code_408">Request Timeout</string>
    <string name="code_409">already exists.</string>
    <string name="code_410">Gone</string>
    <string name="code_411">Length Required</string>
    <string name="code_412">Precondition Failed</string>
    <string name="code_413">Payload Too Large</string>
    <string name="code_414">URI Too Long</string>
    <string name="code_415">Unsupported Media Type</string>
    <string name="code_416">Range Not Satisfiable</string>
    <string name="code_417">Expectation Failed</string>
    <string name="code_418">I'm a teapot</string>
    <string name="code_422">Unprocessable Entity</string>
    <string name="code_425">Too Early</string>
    <string name="code_426">Upgrade Required</string>
    <string name="code_428">Precondition Required</string>
    <string name="code_429">Too Many Requests</string>
    <string name="code_431">Request Header Fields Too Large</string>

    <string name="code_451">Unavailable For Legal Reasons</string>
    <string name="code_500">Fail to connect server.</string>
    <string name="code_501">Not implemented</string>
    <string name="code_502">Bad Gateway</string>

    <string name="code_503">Service Unavailable.</string>

    <string name="code_504">Gateway Timeout</string>
    <string name="code_505">HTTP Version Not Supported</string>
    <string name="code_506">Variant Also Negotiates</string>
    <string name="code_507">Insufficient Storage</string>
    <string name="code_508">Loop Detected</string>
    <string name="code_511">Network Authentication Required</string>
```

```
401 Status code Display Popus Unauthorizedmessage

fun unAuthorizedPopUpView(activity: Activity?) {

   // Handle your logic for 401 (Unauthorized)

}

fun invalidJWTTokenAuth(activity: Activity?) {

    // Handle your logic for 501 (Not implemented)


}
```